# 2 foreach loops with arrays

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

What I am trying to do is get my "$ages" array to display a value once per player in order of the array..
However every time I add the extra for loop with that array, it duplicates each player 20 times, with each array value once. I want 20 players, with the 20 different values of the array one each.

**Here's the current output, that is duplicating each player 20 times.**
http://freerdarts.com/test.php

**Here's the code**

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://freerdarts.com/assets/css/main.css" />
<?php

libxml_use_internal_errors(true);

$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTML(file_get_contents('https://www.leagueleader.net/sharedreport.php?operatorid=98&code=1166aea7-6e0e-4864-8074-8ebd93311041'));
$doc->strictErrorChecking = false;

$pre = [];
$keys = ['name', 'team', 'ppd', 'games', 'wins', 'hats', '3bd', 'ton80','hton','lton','6do','7do','8do','9do'];
$keys2 = ['name', 'mpr', 'games', 'wins','assists', 'hats','whorse','5mr','6mr','7mr','8mr','9mr'];
foreach ($doc->getElementsByTagName('table') as $k => $table) {

    if (strpos($table->getAttribute('class'), 'report') === false) {
        continue;
    }
    foreach ($table->getElementsByTagName('tr') as $i => $tr) {
        if ($tr->parentNode->nodeName === 'thead') continue; // skip headers 
        $row_values = [];
        foreach ($tr->childNodes as $td) {
            $text = trim($td->nodeValue);
            if ($text === '') continue;
            $row_values[] = $text;
        }

        if($k == 1 ){


            $row_values = array_combine($keys, $row_values);

        }else   if($k == 2 ){
            unset($row_values[1]);
        $row_values = array_combine($keys2, $row_values);

        }
          $pre[$row_values['name']][] = $row_values;

    }


}


$combined = [];
foreach($pre as $name => $row){
    $combined[$name] = [
        "name"=> $name,
        "team"=> $row[0]['team'],
        "ppd_01" => $row[0]['ppd'],
        "games_01" => $row[0]['games'],
        "wins_01" => $row[0]['wins'],
        "hats_01" => $row[0]['hats'],
        "3bd" => $row[0]['3bd'],
        "ton80" => $row[0]['ton80'],
        "hton" => $row[0]['hton'],
        "lton" => $row[0]['lton'],
        "6do" => $row[0]['6do'],
        "7do" => $row[0]['7do'],
        "8do" => $row[0]['8do'],
        "9do" => $row[0]['9do'],

        "mpr_crk" => $row[1]['mpr'],
        "games_crk" => $row[1]['games'],
        "wins_crk" => $row[1]['wins'],
        "assists_crk" => $row[1]['assists'],
        "hats_crk" => $row[1]['hats'],
        "whorse" => $row[1]['whorse'],
        "5mr" => $row[1]['5mr'],
        "6mr" => $row[1]['6mr'],
        "7mr" => $row[1]['7mr'],
        "8mr" => $row[1]['8mr'],
        "9mr" => $row[1]['9mr']
    ];
}

//echo '<pre>'.json_encode($combined, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT).'</pre>';
//echo $combined['Ronnie Otto']['ppd_01'];
?>

<?php
// Players Ages
$ages = array(one,two,three,four,five,six,seven,eight,nine,ten,eleven,twelve,thirteen,fourteen,fifteen,sixteen,seventeen,eighteen,nineteen,twenty);

sort($combined);
foreach($combined as $row) {
foreach($ages as $age) {

// Name Corrections
if($row['name'] == 'Scott Sandburg'){ $row['name'] = 'Scott Sandberg'; }

// Profile Images
$profile_image = $row['name'];
$profile_image = str_replace(' ', '_', $profile_image);
?>


<div class="profile">
    <span class="profile_ext"> <img src="../images/profiles/<?=$profile_image?>.jpg" />
    <span class="name"><?=$row['name'];?></span>
    <span class="age"><?=$age;?></span>
    <span class="gamesplayed"><?=$row['games_01']+$row['games_crk'];?></span>
    <span class="blank"></span>
    <!-- Cricket Stats -->
    <span class="cricketmpr"><?=$row['mpr_crk'];?></span>
    <span class="cricket_5mr"><?=$row['5mr'];?></span>
    <span class="cricket_6mr"><?=$row['6mr'];?></span>
    <span class="cricket_7mr"><?=$row['7mr'];?></span>
    <span class="cricket_8mr"><?=$row['8mr'];?></span>
    <span class="cricket_9mr"><?=$row['9mr'];?></span>
    <span class="cricket_whorse"><?=$row['whorse'];?></span>
    <span class="blank"></span>
    <!-- 01 Stats -->
    <span class="o1ppd"><?=$row['ppd_01'];?></span>
    <span class="o1_lton"><?=$row['lton'];?></span>
    <span class="o1_hats"><?=$row['hats_01'];?></span>
    <span class="o1_hton"><?=$row['hton'];?></span>
    </span>
</div>
<?php } } ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you have an inner `foreach()` in your display part...

```
foreach($ages as $age) {
```

this doesn't seem in any way connected to the data you are displaying as there doesn't seem to be an age in the data.

You should also be getting some warnings as

```
$ages = array(one,two,three,four,five,six,seven,eight,nine,ten,eleven,twelve,thirteen,fourteen,fifteen,sixteen,seventeen,eighteen,nineteen,twenty);
```

will show

> Warning: Use of undefined constant one - assumed 'one' (this will
>   throw an Error in a future version of PHP)
>   You should have quotes round the values...

```
$ages = array('one',...
```

If you just want the players listed with the corresponding age, you first need to change

```
foreach($combined as $key => $row) {
// Remove next foreach
// foreach($ages as $age) {
```

Then to display the age, use the $key from the `foreach()` to index the `$ages` array...

```
<span class="age"><?=$ages[$key];?></span>
```

Comment: Thanks, Nigel. I am not getting any errors with that code, just the loop repeating several times. It actually displays the array from one-twenty fully, but not as I expect it to. How do you display the $ages inside the other loop, without it repeating?

Comment: I'm not sure where you get the age from - so not sure what your expecting it to do.

Comment: I want to create an array of 20 ages pertaining to the 20 players. I would just input each players age in order of the display

Comment: I've added to the answer